# How can I scale an embarrassingly parallel jobs across multiple computers in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, embarrassingly-parallel

I have an embarrassingly parallel problem I want to scale across multiple computers using .Net.

I’m currently using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to scale across multiple cores on a single computer but I want to scale further.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's hard to say since you haven't given any details about the problem, but message queuing is an easy way to scale across multiple computers.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve created an open source library you can use to scale embarrassingly parallel solutions across multiple computer using .Net.

http://simplescale.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Dryad/

> Dryad is an infrastructure which allows a programmer to use the resources of a computer cluster or a data center for running data-parallel programs. A Dryad programmer can use thousands of machines, each of them with multiple processors or cores, without knowing anything about concurrent programming.

**UPDATED**:  If you need data intensive parallel processing, check out HDInsight.  If the work is more compute intensive, check out the Microsoft HPC Pack (currently v2012 SP1).

> The essence of HPC is executing code on many machines at the same time. For HPC Pack 2012 SP1, this 
>   means spreading the application’s logic across multiple compute nodes, where each node is a computer 
>   that runs Windows

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/azure/high-perf-computing-on-windows-azure.pdf

Comment: "Microsoft discontinued active development on Dryad, shifting focus to the Apache Hadoop framework" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dryad_%28programming%29